# Jasper report Font not found exception

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

When i am using jasper report on **windows and mac** it works fine, when i deploy my app to **linux machine** and tried to generate the report it throwed

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Times New Roman' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

I know we can resolve the issue by installing the missing fonts in linux machine (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987804/jasper-stops-finding-one-font).  My question is, **Can we pack fonts as jar and giving as package with application**. How to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need Jasper's [font extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) to achieve this. This [blog](http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html) explains the steps to achieve this and extend that to available for PDF export as well.