# Why doesn't jasper report throw a JRFontNotFoundException if font for PDF is missing?

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

I read

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028080/5277820
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549391/5277820
- http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/543275/fonts-problem-while-using-jasper-reports-402-version
- http://refermycode.com/remove-font-dependency-in-jasper-report/

and I expected that Jasper Reports throws a [`JRFontNotFoundException`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRFontNotFoundException.html) if a font is not installed on the machine.

But my application doesn't throw a [`JRFontNotFoundException`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRFontNotFoundException.html), although I have not installed the used font "Helvetica" on any (Jaspersoft Studios, JasperReports, Adobe Acrobat Reader) machine.

**JRXML:**

```
<parameter name="timestamp" class="java.util.Date"/>
[...]
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="16" uuid="0007846a-26f1-457a-a198-67a2f7c8417c">
        <property name="local_mesure_unitwidth" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unitx" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unity" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
        <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
    </reportElement>
    <box padding="2"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font size="8" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1250" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[DATEFORMAT($P{timestamp},"dd.MM HH:mm")]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

**Maven dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-functions</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Java:**

```
private byte[] createPdf() {

    try {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyReport.jasper");
        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(is);
        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        parameters.put("timestamp", new Date());
        JRDataSource jrDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(new Vector(), false);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jrDataSource);
        byte[] pdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        return pdf;
    } catch (JRException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create PDF.", e);
    }
}
```

The reason is that [`JRFontNotFoundException`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRFontNotFoundException.html) is only thrown if font in the attribute `fontName` is not installed:

> Exception raised when a font name used as value for the `fontName` attribute in the report template, is not found in any of the runtime available JasperReports font extensions, nor among the font names available to the Java Virtual Machine.

Is there any way to abort generation of PDF if the font in attribute `pdfFontName` is not installed (instead of using any other installed font)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are setting `pdfFontName` not `fontName`

`pdfFontName` was an old way, now **deprecated** to indicate what font the itext library should use, jasper-reports will not throw `JRFontNotFoundException` if the font is missing, instead itext will throw an exception that is caught and relaunched as a `JRRuntimeException`.

In itext Helvetica is included as `afm` file, hence itext will not throw any exception if this is used, however this does **not guarantee** that your text is **rendered correctly** if you are indicating another font (in your case not indicating = default font) in jasper-reports. In fact this is a mess and both `pdfFontName` and `pfdEncoding` was deprecated.

***Is there any way to abort generation of PDF if the font in attribute pdfFontName is not installed?***

**Don't use `pdfFontName`**, but if you insist (for the sake of the question) then also set `fontName="Helvetica"`, setting the jasper-reports font will raise a `JRFontNotFoundException` if not found.

The **correct way** is to only set the **`fontName`** and then provide **[font-extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/)**, in the font-extension you include the actual `ttf`, indicate the encoding and if it should be embedded.

BTW: I would use encoding Identity-H this is recommend for newer PDF standards and gives you the ability to mix different encoding.