# JasperReports won't work on Amazon EC2 linux ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, jasper-reports, tomcat6

I have a web application on Amazon EC2 and JasperReports doesn't work like on my Windows PC... it comes out with

```
java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found.
```

I installed `liberation-fonts` as suggested by many on google, then I'm trying to set up this option for tomcat:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

I added it to JAVA_OPTS (as CATALINA_OPTS was missing) in etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf, with no effect. Do you have any clues on this?

Comment: I confirm that /etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf is the right place to set such things. But it's insufficient to fix the problem that you are hitting.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811908/jvm-fonts-and-jasperreports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem with Fedora on EC2 once. In that case we solved it with `yum install deja*`. Give that a try.

It seems that the default DejaVu fonts were referenced somewhere, so the above was a simple solution.

Comment: I ended up installing all font packeges I found on yum and it worked. Thanks