# Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, itext, ireport

> iReport Version : 3.7.1

I approached this problem in two ways.

> **My first method**

I am creating a `pdf` page in `iReport` and I have one of the fields (from database) set to a font **Gujarati-Salarl** (A font for a regional language of India).

This font is available in the font list of `iReport`. 
When I hit preview I get the desired output , with the field in the required font style.

Everything till here is fine.

But the `pdf` file generated still contains the same original font in English characters.

The result is same whether i call the report from the application or from a `JAVA` file.

> After a bit of study I found this , **a second method**

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name", "C:\\Gujrati-Saral-1.ttf");
```

This sets the font of the `pdf` to the `ttf` font provided but now the entire `pdf` comes in the Guarati-saral font which is not what I am looking for..

Is there a way to specifically apply this font only to that one particular field?

or

when going by the second method is there a way to not applying the font **Guarati-saral** to all other fields except the required one ?

Comment: Did you use the `Font Extensions`?

Comment: @Alex K I am not sure about how to use them... So I don't think I have used them. Would that be helpful?  How can include in my files..?

Comment: You can read this article: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions

Comment: @Alex I added the font from Tool > Options > ireport. The pdf was outputted with the required font, but when I call the same from the JAVA class I dont get the font displayed. It prints the original font.. What would be the reason for that?

Comment: Is it (the jar file with your font) in classpath?

Comment: Is everything is ok when you are using iReport for exporting report to pdf?

Comment: @AlexK no I have not added any `jar` file with font, everything is fine when exporting the pdf from ireport. How to create the jar file with the font? is there way to do that from ireport itself...?

Comment: You can create the jar in iReport (Options -> Fonts -> Install Font)

Comment: @AlexK I did that as metioned in an earlier comment, that made the exported pdf from ireport have the font i required, but I want to get it run from the java file for that where would the jar file be created after the above process?

Comment: You can create the jar file with font with help of iReport. After that you should add this jar to classpath

Comment: @AlexK Ok...Done...Thanks a lot... Post this as an answer so that it could be helpful to others!!!

Comment: Welcome ))  I've just posted the answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should use the `Font Extensions` mechanism.

After creating the font and exporting it as a jar file you should add generated jar file to the application classpath.

#### a) Creating new font in *iReport* (via Options -> Fonts -> "Install Font" Button)

[image: Creating the new font descriptor in iReport]

#### b) Exporting the new font (or the existing one) as jar file in iReport (via Options -> Fonts -> "Export as extension" Button)

[image]

#### a) Creating new font in *JasperReports Studio* (via Window -> Preferences -> JasperStudio -> Fonts -> "Add" Button)

#### b) Configure your fonts

[image: Exporting font as jar file]

#### c) Create JAR with your fonts in it

[image: Export Font Jar]

[image]

You can find more information about using `Font Extensions` [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions).

Comment: i screwed up the edit mixed around links a bit. can you fix it? it is attempting to be more modern by having screenshots for jaspersoft studio

Comment: The original question was about using *iReport* :). I have [also an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19234053/876298) about using fonts in *Jaspersoft Stuido*

Comment: Mac version doesnt have this option -> fonts option. How do i get around this?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Sorry, I have not Mac to check. Did you try to use *JSS* (Jaspersoft Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

if you have problems displaying UTF-8 characters in the pdf,
from version 4.8.0 of the IReport, no need to do nothing!
Just change the font of the cells in the table from sanserif to Dejavu sans.
thats it.

Answer (score 0):

For those, who need Russian language in Jasper Reports (at least in opennms of old versions), following combination does the trick without using the Font Extension:

Font Name: SanSerif
PDF Font: Courier
PDF Encoding: CP1251
PDF Embedded: Yes (not sure, may be it works even without)

Alexey Bakhmutov

Answer (score -1):

Select the field and go to filed properties and change the

1. select DejaVu Sans as  Font Name
2. select Pdf Encoding to CP1256 (Arabic)
3. select pdf font name to Courier

with these changes in I got arabic data showing in PDF.