# Font is not available to jvm while converting a report from jrxml to pdf

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

I am using eclipse in windows.

I am getting this error while generating pdf file from jrxml file using jar jasperreports-4.1.1.jar. I have manually added font files in my jre from my windows folder and have added font path to path variable but still getting the same error.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : 
pdfFontName   : Arial
pdfEncoding   : Cp1252
isPdfEmbedded : false
```

Another weird thing which I have observed is that when I try the same function for Cambria font, I get a different error.
Below is the error when I use cambria

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'CAMBRIA' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontUtil.checkAwtFont(JRFontUtil.java:358)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledText.getAwtAttributedString(JRStyledText.java:226)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.AbstractTextRenderer.render(AbstractTextRenderer.java:263)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportText(JRPdfExporter.java:2026)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:729)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:2526)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:733)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportFrame(JRPdfExporter.java:2526)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportElements(JRPdfExporter.java:733)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportPage(JRPdfExporter.java:689)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:582)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:376)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JasperExportManager.java:122)
at main.CopyOfTable.runReport(CopyOfTable.java:60)
at main.CopyOfTable.main(CopyOfTable.java:100)
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps:

1. Define your fonts as "font extensions". This involves creating two
   files: jasperreports_extension.properties and fonts.xml. See how it's done in the 
   demo/fonts directory in the JasperReports package you can download
   from http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases.
2. Package your fonts and the font extensions into a JAR file that is available on the classpath.

This works for TrueType and OpenType fonts.

Also:

See Teodor's first comment [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/528625/html-markup-doesnt-work-pdf).

One of many helpful answers on this site is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport).

Good luck.

Comment: i have downloaded jasperReport.5.0.0.jar and added in my classpath but still i have same issue. On close observation there is no fonts.xml in jar file so i manually added in jar and tried it but still no luck.

Comment: You need to download jasperreports-5.0.0-project.zip, not the jar. The project contains the demo/fonts directory, which demonstrates the correct approach. If you follow the example and the documentation [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions), you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue just adding the missing font to OS, in my case, Windows 7. My report does not use the missing font, which was Calibri Light, and always worked in others enviroments.

Answer (score 0):

You fetch following type of error

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the
>   following font

**You must check temp folder in you tomcat directory. If you not found any temp folder, please create temp folder as like**

[image]