# Missing words when theres textfield overflow

Tags: java, jasper-reports, overflow, ireport, textfield

I'm currently using the `jasperreports-4.5.1` library and I'm having problems with the textfield overflow.

I have a one textfield, inside a band, to show an address written in English. This textfield ajust its width automatic to the text because the property `isStrechWithOverFlow` is set to true. What happens is when the lenght of the address is just a little bit loger than the textfield (for example 4 caracters) the textfield does not strech automatically and hides those final caracters. Although, when you have more than 6 characters the sentence is wrapped correctly and hidden part is pasted to the line below.

[image: Screenshot]

In the image attached you'll see a red circle marking the spot where the problem happens. The full address that should appear there is:

```
EDF. KUAI TAK TAK (TAK TAK KAK CHKK), 2 ANDAR c
```

and as you can see the `ANDAR c` part is missing. Here is the code that generates these field:

```
<textfield isstretchwithoverflow="true" isblankwhennull="true">
    <reportelement uuid="82599625-2379-4c37-b390-5fece5e8e828" style="FontStyle" positiontype="Float" mode="Transparent" x="227" y="151" width="224" height="11"></reportelement>
    <textelement verticalalignment="Top">
        <font size="6" isitalic="false"></font>
    </textelement>
    <textfieldexpression></textfieldexpression>
</textfield>
```

Is there any problem with the word wrapper or with strech textfield algorithms? I'm new here so this is just wild guesses. Maybe the problem is in my code.

Please help me, because I don't have any idea how to solve this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iReport, does the problem occur both in the iReport internal previewer AND the PDF previewer? If it formats correctly in the internal previewer but not in the PDF, I suspect you're not using font extensions. You must use font extensions to get the PDFs to format correctly.

You can find a step-by-step explanation of font extensions [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions).

Alex K gives nice documentation on using iReport with font extensions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport).

A demo of how to organize and program font extensions is in the demo/fonts directory of the JasperReports project zip file available on the [releases page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the `stretchType` of the `reportElement`

```
 stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"
```