# Jasper JRFontNotFoundException when set font

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have an executable jar that I use to create pdf reports. To avoid problems with the fonts I set an specific fontName (DejaVu Sans) for all the texts in the reports and exported the fonts as said by many (for example, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport) ).

I included the exported jar (myFonts.jar) in the executable jar, but when I try to execute my jar, it returns the error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException:  
                                 Font 'DejaVu Sans' is not available to the JVM.
```

I also tried using the jasperreports-fonts.jar (the default one) instead of mine, and it didn't work either.

I have reviewed a lot of posts, answers and forums and I've been stuck in this for a while now. :S

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: To fix this put the jars in the system path to let the system find them.  There are options for the classpath in the iReport tool also.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? I would like to distribute only one jar (the executable one, with the libraries included)

Comment: If you can package that jar in the executable one manually then it should work, I believe.  Check the meta and structure inside the jar.

Comment: No, it doesn't :( I tried putting the myFonts.jar in the classpath (outside) and it worked, but when packaging in the executable jar it didn't

Comment: @ChristianVielma Did you use the [*Font Extensions*](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions) mechanism?

Comment: @AlexK yes. Currently I made it work using an external jar, but strangely it doesn't work if I include the extension in the same jar :S (although it doesn't make any sense)