# How to display Hindi font in the pdf exported?

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports, hindi

I am trying to display *Hindi font* in the pdf file generated using *iReport*. I've added Hindi ttf font in the *iReport* for the same. *iReport* tool is displaying Hindi font properly in the *iReport* viewer but when I am exporting it into a pdf file I am not getting anything printed in the pdf file.

Comment: [This SE question][1] looks like will solve your issue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport

Comment: @AyushBilala Did you read this post: [hindi fonts words are changed when embedded in pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18313080/876298)?

Comment: @AyushBilala Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: I am using lohita-devanagari.jar as font extensions

Comment: Is there a solution for this? I am also not able to do with Lohit Devanagari extension jar