# Jasper generated pdf report character rendering issue for language like Hindi

Tags: formatting, jasper-reports, render, hindi

Report created from jasper not rendering properly for pdf in case of Hindi language.

e.g.
Correct Rendering should look like that

```
५ दिन
```

but rendered it wrongly.

Getting rendering issue for some characters only.

My application is running on Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.5.0-23-generic x86_64).

I used Mangal ttf file for rendering Hindi language.

I have tried following:

1. ireport pdf ecoding setup.

   > fontName="Mangal" size="9" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="akshar.ttf"   pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"
2. Font Extension and included jar file into my application.
3. Even upgraded my application jasper library.
4. Upgrading of Mangal ttf file.
5. Upgraded ubuntu specifically mscorefonts.

Help needed ASAP.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [hindi fonts words are changed when embedded in pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18313080/876298) & [How to display Hindi font in the pdf exported?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18847367/876298)

Comment: possible duplicate of [formatting a string to a currency format in jasper report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913495/formatting-a-string-to-a-currency-format-in-jasper-report)