# JasperReports does not generate report with bold

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have read 
[JasperReports - Fonts Sample (version 6.2.0)](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/) official tutorial to generate my reports the same way they were designed with font styles.

Here's my `jasperreports_extension.properties`:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.simple.font.families=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.dejavu=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.arial=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/fonts.xml
```

Here's my `fonts.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
        <!--
        <locales>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <locale>de_DE</locale>
        </locales>
        -->
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Serif">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans Mono">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Arial">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arial.ttf</normal>
        <bold>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arialbd.ttf</bold>
        <italic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ariali.ttf</italic>
        <boldItalic>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/arialbi.ttf</boldItalic>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <fontFamily name="Arial Black">
        <normal>net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/ariblk.ttf</normal>
        <pdfEncoding>Identity-H</pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded>true</pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial Black</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial Black</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>

    <!--
        Mapping Java logical fonts, for the sake of HTML export only.
    -->

    <fontFamily name="SansSerif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Serif">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Serif', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
    <fontFamily name="Monospaced">
        <exportFonts>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
            <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'DejaVu Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        </exportFonts>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

I placed the fonts in my jar but when I generate the report the font styles still does not appear. Am I missing something?

Comment: I do not think you have problem with itext library, maybe you have the jasperreports-fonts-6.x.x in your classpath and it is using this instead of your font-extension...  This is most probably a classpath problem (probably more then one jasperreports_extension.properties)

Comment: See: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have the correct path to your xml and ttf files, it follows same style as java package.

*Example*

If your `jasperreports_extension.properties` is in the project root folder (that I would suggest since it need to be found by jasper-reports) and you have the `fonts.xml` and `ttf` files in a folder that are called `fonts`.

The reference in `jasperreports_extension.properties` would be:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.myFonts=fonts/fonts.xml
```

And in `fonts.xml`

```
<fontFamily name="DejaVu Sans">
    <normal>fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf</normal>
    <bold>fonts/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf</bold>
    .....
</fontFamily>
```

If you still have problem I suggest that you use an IDE like [ireport](/questions/tagged/ireport) or [jaspersoft-studio](/questions/tagged/jaspersoft-studio) they will let you automatically generate a jar for the font-extension (including your ttf's).

It will then be enough that you included this jar in your classpath when generating your pdf export.

How to generate font extensions jar using [iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/ireport-fonts) or in [JasperSoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/custom-font-font-extension)

Comment: What is wrong in my files? I download via maven the jar and modified these files and added my fonts only. And what is even more curious is that I am using Arial and Arial Black with or without bold. I just generated the jar by reading the tutorial you provided and still does not work.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Are the jasperreports_extension.properties in root folder, are the fonts.xml deployed in net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/ folder are the ttf deployed in net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/dejavu/ and net/sf/jasperreports/fonts/arial/??? seems strange that you made a package that is the same as jasper report...

Comment: If you generate as tutorial it will work make sure that the jar it is in your class path (and remove old jasperreports_extension.properties)....

Comment: Naturally the textField need to use a font as indicated in fonts.xml see this question for example of font-extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940126/how-can-i-display-%C2%A3%E2%84%A6%E2%82%AC%CE%B1%CF%80%E2%85%94-in-jasperserver-pdf-using-ireport

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232826/when-export-a-report-to-pdf-change-the-font/19234053#19234053

Comment: Is it possible to upload my jar here in stackoverflow?

Comment: Would you take a look if I place it in Google Drive and share a link here?

Comment: Sure, if in the next 10 min.

Comment: Done: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4dyL0GPpLokbk1QOGgxQW81QWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99350/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-philippe-gioseffi).