# Jasper Reports does not bold text in a pdf file

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Using jasper reports (1.3) together with itext library (1.3.1) to make pdf reports. Font is defined as follows:

```
<reportFont name="font-normal" isDefault="true" fontName="Code2000" size="9" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="CODE2000.TTF" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

We explicitly set isBold="true", however nothing in the report is bold. The font CODE2000.TTF can be used in MS Word with bold style. We also tried without success setting isBold="true" on the  element inside  like in:

```
<textField>
  <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="120" width="694" height="14"/>
  <textElement>
    <font size="9" pdfFontName="CODE2000.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true" isBold="true"/>
  </textElement>
  <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
     "TITLE:"+str($P{title})
  </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does your font have a bold TTF, too? if yes, it should be added to the font definition...

Comment: I could not find a bold version of Code200

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/75965/distinguishing-real-and-faux-bold-and-italics

Comment: plz reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534238/jasperreports-does-not-generate-report-with-bold