# Report won't show on Windows but shows on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jasper-reports, tomcat7

I am developing a webapp which produce PDF document with iReport.

I am working on a Ubuntu machine.

The reports are well displayed on a tomcat installed on **Ubuntu**, but if I deploy the WAR on a tomcat server that is installed on a **Windows** machine, the characters are not displayed.

I use the SansSerif font.

Is it a known issue?

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: no, I use the font already packaged with iReport. As sans serif is known by Windows, I don't know why the PDF are not well displayed.

Comment: You should use the *Font Extensions*. The instruction is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8999021/876298)

Comment: I use iReport as an Eclipse plugin, I don't have these screens in Eclipse.

Comment: This [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19234053/876298) about the Studio