# Barcode text is empty using Jasper Report and Barbecue

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode, export-to-pdf, barbecue

I want to show on my Jasper Report one EAN13 barcode WITH text. So far the preview in JasperSoft Studio 6.5.1 is working great, I see the barcode and the text under it:

[image: preview in JasperSoft Studio]

This is the code part of it:

```
    <componentElement>
        <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="111" width="130" height="30" uuid="48d9d636-7e04-43df-9fa2-5c3f6edf27da"/>
        <c:barbecue xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="EAN13" drawText="true" checksumRequired="false">
            <c:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{EAN}]]></c:codeExpression>
        </c:barbecue>
    </componentElement>
```

My problem is, that if I build this .jasper report and deploy is to my Java webapp and print it out into one .pdf the text under the barcode is empty or white, but I see there nothing, only the barcode.

[image: empty text under barcode]

What do I need to change to view the text also in the webapp version of the report? Thank you.

EDIT.:

I got this answer on the Jaspersoft forum:

"It's not really a problem with JasperReports but with Barbeque. There's a bug in calculating the text area size. Fixing barbeque and replacing it in JasperReports solved the problem for me. "

Sadly I'm not closer to solve the issue, because I tried to resize the barcode element to the possible maximum, but nothing changed...

Comment: Looks like a font issue. Did you try to use different fonts? Did you try to use font extensions?

Comment: I don't know how to change the font sadly in JasperSoft Studio... Can I do this via source code? Font extension is new to me, can you send me a description about it?

Comment: [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8985497/876298) & [When export a report to PDF change the font](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19232826/876298)

Comment: `Can I do this via source code?` - Yes. You can set font at *jrxml* file (direct or with help of style)

Comment: Can you please post example, how to set font for this barbecue element? I can't find any setting regarding the fonts in the properties and also couldn't find anything for the source code :( The other elements have Dejavu Sant fonts and they are displayed in the pdf without any error.

Comment: Okay, defined one style and applied to this element. Changed the font, font size... Nothing changed :(

Comment: What is a value of `$F{EAN}`? How to test this issue?

Comment: Value of the test ean is: 694105740231. I can send you the whole .jrxml is that helps :)

Comment: I uploaded it to Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/X6WQq0m1

Comment: Your sample is working well for me - I checked at JSS

Comment: <band height="379" splitType="Stretch">
   <componentElement>
    <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="111" width="130" height="30"/>
    <c:barbecue xmlns:c="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" type="EAN13" drawText="true" checksumRequired="false">
     <c:codeExpression><![CDATA["694105740231"]]></c:codeExpression>
    </c:barbecue>
   </componentElement>
  </band>

Comment: Looks like really font problem. I'll try from Java code

Comment: I have Glassfish as server, but if you got the barcode AND the text, then I don't know what I am missing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183823/discussion-between-alex-k-and-voriand).

Comment: All other reports using this DejavuSans font as well and they are printed without any errors. But I will try this font extension as well, maybe...

Comment: We observed this happens with the Barbecue component when the JVM is started with the -Djava.awt.headless=true property. I'm afraid this is a Barbecue bug we cannot fix, so we suggest to use the Barcode4J component instead.