# Cannot use custom font on iReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

How do you properly import a font on the *fonts* folder of iReport? I am using version 3.0.0. Say I have font X. In the iReport UI, I can see X in the dropdown both for *Font Name* and *PDF Font Name.*

Now, I have java web app that fetches the dynamic PDF (uses the generated jasper report with some parameters something like JRBeanDataCollection). Using font X will cause a file not found exception (because the PDF wasn't generated?).

How do you do it? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport)