# When Report Shown As Pdf from web application Hindi (Indian lang) text not displayed

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, hindi

I am trying to show *JasperReports* report from web application which content some marathi (indian regional language) text.

When I run preview in *iReport* it looks perfect but when I try it from web application to view report as in pdf format then text not shown.

Here is what I try to do.

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("report/name.jasper");

Map param = new HashMap();
param.put("para", "1");

byte[] bytes = JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(is, param, con);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
outStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

I also suggested that to add ***jasperreports.properties*** are as follows

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1250
```

but when I use this property text shows like "?????"

This is the preview from *iReport*:
[image: This is the preview from jasper ireport]

This is the preview when I shown report as pdf from my web application:
[image: This is the preview when I shown report as pdf from my web application]

This is preview when I use ***net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1250***
[image: This is preview when I use net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1250]

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: no.. i retrived field from database

Comment: I did not ask you about using datasource (database)...

Comment: no i didn't use font extensions..is it necessory??? i dnt know how to use it in jasper report

Comment: You can find some information in [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8985497/876298) post

Comment: k bro i have tried many font but it didn't work for me. may be it happen because i have make use of google input languge to store regional language field in database.

Comment: **Please Give Some Reply To Solve This Problem. I am retriving unicode string from database ex. in database feild it stored like this मराठी and when i try to retrive in jasper report as pdf it shows none**