# Changing ireport to use unicode for fields

Tags: unicode, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

How can i change or force ireport to display unicode characters like russian etc.?
I have tried searching it on jasper site but had no luck or relevant answers.

I have this in the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports"

<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{NEWSTATUS}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Also have this screenshots for the pdf report

http://prntscr.com/7yayn6

The Excel one shows it correct

http://prntscr.com/7yayf4

Using iReport 3.7.2 fontName : Tahoma. CSV report also works correct .

Comment: Sanity Check: are you in fact using a font that contains Cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of fonts. You can attach a font library to use any font you like: [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport) or just use **Arial** which works fine with Cyrillic.