# Installing font in PDF for iReport designer 5.1.0 (Mac)

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport

I am having difficulty trying to embed a font into a pdf generated from iReport 5.1.0.

All documentations/articles I have come across on the net point to the windows version where you choose Tools->Options->Fonts then go through the wizard process but unfortunately the mac version doesnt have this option anywhere.

If i can get any pointers on how to do this via the software options,amending my report xml or java I would be grateful.

Comment: In Java: it is just a jar file. You should add it to classpath. You can create *jar* manually. More info here: [Font is not available to the JVM with Jasper Reports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3811908/876298)

Comment: Did you try to use Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use custom fonts when creating pdf using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985497/use-custom-fonts-when-creating-pdf-using-ireport)