# Ubuntu command-not-found fc-list jasper report net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException

Tags: java, linux, jasper-reports, ubuntu-12.04, truetype

I have an app whitch use a report made with JasperReport, but when I try generated the report this throw a *net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Nimbus Mono L' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details*. I have  embebed the fonts in the report, and it's work in the server development but not work in the server producction.

I try install de font in my server producction (Ubuntu) but the commands fc-list and fc-cache not work, throws *-bash: fc-list: command not found*

My server producction is only command line, info of my server:

uname -a:

Linux crtfacntyp1 3.2.0-33-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 18 16:29:15 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/*-release:

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu

DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04

DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise

DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"

NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.1 LTS, Precise Pangolin"

ID=ubuntu

ID_LIKE=debian

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.1 LTS)"

VERSION_ID="12.04"

any idea? please help me :(

Comment: you need to add the font under java fonts directory

Comment: check out this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811908/jvm-fonts-and-jasperreports

Comment: I have the file ttf, where I put it?

Comment: I have already sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it no contains the font nimbus mono

Comment: have u added the fonts directory to classpath?

Comment: if the installation does not contain you font and if u have a ttf file, add the path of the file to CLASSPATH

Comment: My web project have the project dependecy, this dependency have the report. Inside the jar of the dependency exist the ttf file, and the report reference the ttf file by the relative path.  how I added to the classpath?

Comment: And I don't understand why work in develop but not in producction :(

Comment: I can resolved my problem!!
In iReport, add de ttf file: Tools -> Options -> Fonts -> Install Fonts, after select de file ttf. After de install the font in the iReport, in same windown  select the font installed and select the option "Export as extension", this generate a jar file. I added this file jar to the classpath of my app and this work!!!!

Answer (score 0):

create a new directory under "/usr/share/fonts". For example, I created directory:

```
mkdir /usr/share/fonts/GlobalFonts
```

to store a collection of fonts used in your project. To make sure that the fonts is accessible to the world, do

```
chmod 775 -R /usr/share/fonts/GlobalFonts
```

Then all needs to be done is run
`fc-cache` command on that directory,

e.g

```
cd /usr/share/fonts
fc-cache GlobalFonts
```

Comment: I try install de font in my server producction (Ubuntu) but the commands fc-list and fc-cache not work, throws -bash: fc-list: command not found