# Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM on WAS

Tags: jasper-reports

While downloading Jsperreport in PDF format I am getting below error:

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM.

It is working fine on local where I am using tomcat server.
But getting exception on websphere.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what is your local operating system (i guess windows?)
what is the the os where the jvm is running? (i guess not windows)

if it is linux you have to install the windows fonts on the maschine
take a look at: [Font is not available to the JVM with Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811908/jvm-fonts-and-jasperreports)