# JRProperties became deprecated, recommended way of replacing

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The [`JRProperties`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRProperties.html) class has been annotated as deprecated and replaced by [`JRPropertiesUtil`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRPropertiesUtil.html) as stated in the documentation

I've been using it to set the properties in a following way (since it was a class providing static methods),

```
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", defaultPDFFont);
JRProperties.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", "true");
   (...)
```

Which is I presume an unrecommended way of setting the properties now.

---

I've found two ways of doing so in compliance with API documentation, namely by directly using instance of [`JasperReportsContext`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReportsContext.html):

```
JasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
jasperReportsContext.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", "true");
jasperReportsContext.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", defaultPDFFont);
   (...)
```

or by passing the `JasperReportsContext` instance to `JRPropertiesUtil`:

```
JasperReportsContext jasperReportsContext = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil jrPropertiesUtil = JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(jasperReportsContext);
jrPropertiesUtil.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", "true");
jrPropertiesUtil.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", defaultPDFFont);
   (...)
```

So my question is:

**What is the recommended way to set properties for the Report Printer?**

Comment: I just had couple days off, but I accepted your answer now. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for accept, have a great day...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in your current suggest metod, but if you are looking for normal way to set properties.

The properties are loaded from `.properties` files and your `jrxml` file.

**This is the override structure**

1. Loads properties from `default.jasperreports.properties` in the distribution
2. Loads/override properties from  `jasperreports.properties` if provided in root package of your distribution
3. Loads/override property if specified in jrxml **report** level

   ```
   <jasperReport...>
      <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font" value="true"/>
      ...
   </jasperReport>
   ```
4. Loads/override property if specified in jrxml **element** level

   ```
   <reportElement>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.html.class" value="test"/>
   </reportElement>
   ```

You can also set **dynamic properties** in jrxml using

```
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.sheet.name"><![CDATA[$F{SheetName}]]></propertyExpression>
```

Read more to understand how to use IDE: [properties-how-use-additional-properties-build-enhanced-reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/properties-how-use-additional-properties-build-enhanced-reports)

So where should you put your property `net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font=true`?

You should **not use** this it will create export inconsistencies, you should use font-extensions, please see my answer on this [Font is not available to the JVM with Jasper Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811908/jvm-fonts-and-jasperreports/35549391#35549391)

If you don't care put it in the  `jasperreports.properties` or `jrxml` report level

Answer (score 0):

The two solutions you found are both valid for setting global properties.

They do the same thing, JRPropertiesUtil.setProperty() calls JasperReportsContext.setProperty().

I would recommend the first one solely because it's shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line in order to pass the parameter to the jasper context.`JRPropertiesUtil.asBoolean("net.sf.jasperreports.awt.ignore.missing.font", true);`

This workes and will print an error on the console.

> 2021-08-30 22:05:08 FontUtil [WARN] Font 'calibri' is not available to the JVM. For more details, see http:/