# How to change font name dynamically?

Tags: java, dynamic, fonts, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper jar to generate report on my J2EE project. I am able to generate the PDFs successfully without any issues. However I want the font name to be dynamically changed for all my PDFs based on settings which we configure on one place.

I came to know Conditional style which is useful to accomplish this. However I do have hundreds of fonts which cannot be conditionally styled on each and every place. This will make the report more worst.

I am looking for a suitable solution which helps me to change the fonts on jasper PDFs dynamically.

Comment: Conditional styles is special for such cases. You don't need to recompile the templates to use new changed style(s)

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way I can come up with is to use default style in report and change its font name via java before you fill the report.

**Example**

Set a style (I will use default style) in jrxml, since this way I don't need to assign it to `textField` and it's quicker to get from `JasperReport` object

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="reputation" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a88bd694-4f90-41fc-84d0-002b90b2d73e">
    .....
   <style name="myStyle" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>
    ....
</jasperReport>
```

in java loaded your report (jrxml), change default style font name and then fill the report

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jmyReport.jrxml");
report.getDefaultStyle().setFontName("NewFontName");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, paramMap,datasource);
```

> Hower remember you need to add all your font's in [Font Extensions!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549391/5292302), if you like to ensure that they are rendered correctly in your pdf export on client machine.

You can also use non default style, in this case you need to assign it to `textField` and find it in the `JRStyle[] styles = report.getStyles();` by comparing on [JRStyle#getName()](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRStyle.html#getName--)

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.
report.getDefaultStyle().setFontName("NewFontName");
What are all the font name can i assign here, can you give some examples.

Comment: @SrinathMahe Name of a font like "SansSerif", "DejaVu Sans", "Arial" etc, however watch out if you like to render it correctly in pdf you need [font-extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811908/font-is-not-available-to-the-jvm-with-jasper-reports/35549391#35549391). You need to study careful what this means before you start to generate pdf with fonts that user may not have installed on pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
report.getDefaultStyle().setFontName("NewFontName");
```

Incase using `jasperreports-fonts-6.10.0.jar`, `"NewFontName"` is family font name (ex : sans-serif) which is declared in `jasperreports_extension.properties`, isnt't it?

ex:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.sans-serif=fonts/sans-serif.xml
```

Comment: I found right way : "NewFontName" is font name which is setting in fonts.xml inner font extention (jar).
ex : report.getDefaultStyle().setFontName("Helvetica");
and fonts.xml has Helvetica :
    <fontFamily name="Helvetica">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Helvetica/Helvetica.ttf]]></normal>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts />
    </fontFamily>