# Is it required to install font on production servers to generate report using jasper?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReport-5.6.0 to design the jasper report. then I am pushing that jrxml file to the code. I have added a plugin to generate the jasper file during the build process.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\templates\\report\\jrxml</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\templates\\report\\compiled\\</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>6.16.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

On production, the reports are getting generated. The production server is a Linux machine. Do I need to install the fonts I used to generate the jrxml file in the server to generate the jasper files properly?

I know this will be a vague question. But please try to resolve my doubt. I need this information to identify the root cause for the behavior of the report in a different machine.

Comment: You should use font-extension (not install font's on server), see this answer to understand the difference https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549391/5292302

Comment: I'm closing it as a duplicate (since you are asking about this issue), even if the accepted answer on that question is wrong :D, you solve errors related to font by installing, but it's not the correct method.