# Will the net.sf.jasperreports » jasperreports-fonts maven dependency add Arial Font?

Tags: jvm, jasper-reports

I'm getting the exception `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM`

So after some reading I found a maven dependency which seems to add the Arial font.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts/6.20.0

Will this dependency add the Arial font, so jasperreports can use it?

Comment: You need to use font-extension, arial is not included in jasper-reports fonts, you need to make your own see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549391/5292302

Comment: What about this one? I read it's including arial. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mpobjects.jasperreports.font/jasperreports-fonts-liberation/2.1.2   mentioned here https://jar-download.com/?search_box=jasperreports+fonts

Comment: Yeah maybe (I don't know about this one), but it's easy also to do your own font-extension, follow links on the bottom (depending on your IDE) of the answer I linked.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a try. But only on Monday. Thank you very much.

Comment: Finally it got merged and it worked. Thank you very much.